# Calling Inherited IUnknown::Release() in a destructor

Tags: c++, com, directx, virtual-destructor

Why does calling the inherited IUnknown::Release() function on a IWICImagingFactory object in a destructor cause a "CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated" to be shown each entry in the object's virtual function table (__vfptr)?

This is in reference to an earlier question I posted but I've since realized that the problem only occurs in the destructor. The virtual function table appears valid anywhere else I have checked. However, once in the destructor all entries are shown with the CXX0030 error and attempting to call the inherited IUknown::Release() fails.

Edit: Here is some code to demonstrate:

```
HRESULT DemoApp::CreateDeviceIndependentResources()
{
HRESULT hr;


hr = D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &mpDirect2DFactory);


if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WICImagingFactory,
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&mpWICFactory)
        );
}

//CoCreateInstance returns S_OK.
//Other unrelated code here.
}

HRESULT DemoApp::CreateDeviceResources()
{
HRESULT hr;
//Other unrelated code here for creating device-dependant resources.
//mpBackgroundBitmap is a ID2D1Bitmap*.
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = LoadBitmapFromFile(
            mpRenderTarget,
            mpWICFactory,
            L".\\background.png",
            0,
            0,
            &mpBackgroundBitmap);
    }
}


//The below LoadBitmapFromFile() code is taken directly from an MSDN sample.
//I didn't write it.

HRESULT DemoApp::LoadBitmapFromFile(
ID2D1RenderTarget *pRenderTarget,
IWICImagingFactory *pIWICFactory,
PCWSTR uri,
UINT destinationWidth,
UINT destinationHeight,
ID2D1Bitmap **ppBitmap
)
{
IWICBitmapDecoder *pDecoder = NULL;
IWICBitmapFrameDecode *pSource = NULL;
IWICStream *pStream = NULL;
IWICFormatConverter *pConverter = NULL;
IWICBitmapScaler *pScaler = NULL;

HRESULT hr = pIWICFactory->CreateDecoderFromFilename(
    uri,
    NULL,
    GENERIC_READ,
    WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad,
    &pDecoder
    );

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    // Create the initial frame.
    hr = pDecoder->GetFrame(0, &pSource);
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{

    // Convert the image format to 32bppPBGRA
    // (DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM + D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED).
    hr = pIWICFactory->CreateFormatConverter(&pConverter);

}


if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    // If a new width or height was specified, create an
    // IWICBitmapScaler and use it to resize the image.
    if (destinationWidth != 0 || destinationHeight != 0)
    {
        UINT originalWidth, originalHeight;
        hr = pSource->GetSize(&originalWidth, &originalHeight);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            if (destinationWidth == 0)
            {
                FLOAT scalar = static_cast<FLOAT>(destinationHeight) / static_cast<FLOAT>(originalHeight);
                destinationWidth = static_cast<UINT>(scalar * static_cast<FLOAT>(originalWidth));
            }
            else if (destinationHeight == 0)
            {
                FLOAT scalar = static_cast<FLOAT>(destinationWidth) / static_cast<FLOAT>(originalWidth);
                destinationHeight = static_cast<UINT>(scalar * static_cast<FLOAT>(originalHeight));
            }

            hr = pIWICFactory->CreateBitmapScaler(&pScaler);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                hr = pScaler->Initialize(
                        pSource,
                        destinationWidth,
                        destinationHeight,
                        WICBitmapInterpolationModeCubic
                        );
            }
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                hr = pConverter->Initialize(
                    pScaler,
                    GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA,
                    WICBitmapDitherTypeNone,
                    NULL,
                    0.f,
                    WICBitmapPaletteTypeMedianCut
                    );
            }
        }
    }
    else // Don't scale the image.
    { 
        hr = pConverter->Initialize(
            pSource,
            GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA,
            WICBitmapDitherTypeNone,
            NULL,
            0.f,
            WICBitmapPaletteTypeMedianCut
            );
    }
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{

    // Create a Direct2D bitmap from the WIC bitmap.
    hr = pRenderTarget->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(
        pConverter,
        NULL,
        ppBitmap
        );
}

SafeRelease(&pDecoder);
SafeRelease(&pSource);
SafeRelease(&pStream);
SafeRelease(&pConverter);
SafeRelease(&pScaler);

return hr;
}

//Now I call SafeRelease() in my destructor and the virtual function table entires are showing the error.
DemoApp::~DemoApp()
{
SafeRelease(&mpDirect2DFactory);
SafeRelease(&mpWICFactory); //here is the problem apparently
SafeRelease(&mpDWriteFactory); 
SafeRelease(&mpRenderTarget);
SafeRelease(&mpBackgroundBitmap);

}

//SafeRelease is defined as:
template<class Interface>
inline void SafeRelease(Interface** ppInterfaceToRelease)
{
if(*ppInterfaceToRelease != NULL)
{
    (*ppInterfaceToRelease)->Release();
    (*ppInterfaceToRelease) = NULL;
        }

}
```

The problem is when I call SafeRelease() on the WICFactory object, I get:
First-chance exception at 0x0024e135 in DemoApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x6d5c28f0.
Unhandled exception at 0x0024e135 in DemoApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x6d5c28f0.

Comment: Post complete but minimal example code that exhibits the problem. Also please clarify your description. It is too hazy.

Comment: -1 the question is hazy and without code, and the OP is explaining it piecemeal in comments instead of fixing it.

Comment: I updated the post to include code relevant to the object in question and how I am using it along with a better description of the problem. I would fix it but I don't know how other than to call SafeRelease() outside of the destructor but there seems no reason I should have to as far as I can tell.

Comment: your question is about the destructor code. then a list of constructors and all their code is relevant. it sounds like uninitialized or willy-nilly copied pointers. the `SafeRelease` thing is just added complexity, not useful, and as you can see from the argument passing (pointer to pointer instead of pointer reference) it's written by a C programmer. However, C++ has some facilities and conventions that help, in particular using *smart pointers*.

Answer (score 5):

I struggled with this problem lately too. The problem is that the creation and release of `IWICImagingFactory` depends on `CoInitialize`/`CoUninitialize` being called before and after, respectively. In your application it is likely that `CoUninitialize()` is called before the `IWICImagingFactory` is released in the destructor, which causes a crash. Note that `ID2D1RenderTarget` and such do not seem to be affected and can still be released after `CoUninitialize()` is called.

Remove the call to `CoUninitialize()` from `RunMessageLoop()` or wherever it is and put it after the release call in the destructor and the crash should go away.

Answer (score 1):

Calling virtual functions inside the constructor or destructor does not call the function you assume it will call. It always results in call to the functions of that same class.

<strike>You can assume virtual dispatch is disabled in constructor and destructors.</strike>

An more appropriate way of saying this is:

> During the execution of a constructor or destructor, virtual calls on the object for which the constructor or destructor is run behave as if the dynamic type of the object expression used in the call is equal to the class of the constructor or destructor.

Courtesy: A lengthy discussion in C++ Lounge, Where finally, @JohannesSchaublitb came up with this apt definition, which most of us seemed to agree on.

Comment: @user974967 You can look about this issue in this [FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c%2B%2B-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.7)

Comment: I understand the problem of calling a virtual function if it is a part of the same class as the constructor or destructor, but I do not understand why it is a problem if the virtual function is a part of another class entirely. What I am attempting to do is done in the MSDN tutorials. The destructor is in my App class and the virtual function I am calling is from a class in a library.

Comment: @user974967 then you probably should attach some code piece to better understand the problem. From your description it seems that you call virtual function of inherited class, not a method of member object.

Comment: -1 "You can assume virtual dispatch is disabled in constructor and destructors." no you can't

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach: The downvote calls for an explanation.`Why?`

Comment: @Als: as this appears on my screen, my explanation appears right above your query for an explanation. if it doesn't on your screen then Sumthingg's Wring™. do you want me to post a screenshot?

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach: Ofcourse, I meant Why, You cannot assume virtual dispatch is disabled in constructors and destructors? & I don't think the screenshot you will post will have answer to that.

Comment: @Als: oh. it's because virtual dispatch *is not disabled* in constructors and destructors. see [this FAQ item](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.5) and the following item(s).

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach: The statement has the word `assume` and I think that holds good. Whenever a virtual function is called inside a constructor and a destructor One can *assume* the dispatch is disabled because it *behaves* as if an call normal call to function of that class. This is ofcourse from point of view of the user, What goes inside is different but anything associated with an virtual mechanism is an implementation detail so why fret about the dynamics? As your link suggests,the behavior can be simulated but only by additional mechanisms, so the statement holds good.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach: Can't jump in to the Lounge at this moment(the network at workplace doesn't like the C++ Chat), but I think I will get there sometime later during the day after work to seek an explanation of the `no......`